# Link from HTML to android app

Tags: php, android, html

I want to make a link from html direct to android app.
For example for the email activation that send to user

```
<p>If you want to activation your account, click this 
 <a href='http://localhost/mobiletest'>Aktivasi</a>
</p>
```

From email, i want to direct link to activation activity in android. How to make it in html code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In addition you can take the tour at: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at the `Deeplink` feature of Android, see more information here ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html))

Or you can use [this third party library](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch) from Airbnb.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to insert your Google Play link like:

```
<p>If you want to activation your account, click this 
 <a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domain.appname'>Aktivasi</a>
</p>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what if the application has not been put in google play?

Comment: Then you should take a look here https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents